# How to create an animation like in Facebook Pages top menu?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, animation, facebook-pop

In facebook'a new app, Pages, when you swipe down the menu appears at the top. The animation I am trying to do is the animation when you tap the settings button which is when each cell moves to the left one at a time, but very smoothly. How can I achieve such an animation without using Facebook's pop engine in Objective C ?

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that each cell is probably a custom subclass of `UIView` (i.e. not `UITableViewCell` or other apple class) so you will have to design your UI carefully.

The animation, however, is easily achievable using the `UIView` class. [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html) is a good place to start to learn about animation.

What you want is something like:

```
NSTimeInterval delay = 0.2;
for (UIView *myView in myViewArray) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:delay options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
       /*
        * This is where you set the properties you want to animate.
        * If you're using AutoLayout (i.e. NSLayoutConstraint) you need to set the constant property of the relevant constraint, not the view's frame property.
        */
    } completion:nil];
    delay += 0.2;
}
```

This will provide you with animations that occur one after the other (0.2 seconds apart).